# How to store numerical lookup table in Python (with labels)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a scientific model which I am running in Python which produces a lookup table as output. That is, it produces a many-dimensional 'table' where each dimension is a parameter in the model and the value in each cell is the output of the model.

My question is how best to store this lookup table in Python. I am running the model in a loop over every possible parameter combination (using the fantastic `itertools.product` function), but I can't work out how best to store the outputs.

It would seem sensible to simply store the output as a `ndarray`, but I'd really like to be able to access the outputs based on the parameter values not just indices. For example, rather than accessing the values as `table[16][5][17][14]` I'd prefer to access them somehow using variable names/values, for example:

`table[solar_z=45, solar_a=170, type=17, reflectance=0.37]`

or something similar to that. It'd be brilliant if I were able to iterate over the values and get their parameter values back - that is, being able to find out that `table[16]...` corresponds to the outputs for solar_z = 45.

Is there a sensible way to do this in Python?

Comment: Check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: Or maybe [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use a database? I have found [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) (and the official Python driver, [Pymongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Python+Language+Center)) to be a wonderful tool for scientific computing. Here are some advantages:

- Easy to install - simply download the executables for your platform (2 minutes tops, seriously).
- Schema-less data model
- Blazing fast
- Provides map/reduce functionality
- Very good querying functionalities

So, you could store each entry as a MongoDB entry, for example:

```
{"_id":"run_unique_identifier",
 "param1":"val1",
 "param2":"val2" # etcetera
}
```

Then you could query the entries as you will:

```
import pymongo
data = pymongo.Connection("localhost", 27017)["mydb"]["mycollection"]
for entry in data.find(): # this will yield all results
 yield entry["param1"] # do something with param1
```

Whether or not MongoDB/pymongo are the answer to your specific question, I don't know. However, you could really benefit from checking them out if you are into data-intensive scientific computing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the results by name, then you could use a python nested dictionary instead of ndarray, and serialize it in a .JSON text file using `json` module.

Comment: A nested dictionary would not give him the ability to retrieve the values by using (name, value) parameters

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a numpy ndarray for the data (as you do now), and write a parser function to convert the query values into row/column indices.

For example:

```
solar_z_dict = {...}
solar_a_dict = {...}
...
def lookup(dataArray, solar_z, solar_a, type, reflectance):
  return dataArray[solar_z_dict[solar_z] ], solar_a_dict[solar_a], ...]
```

You could also convert to string and eval, if you want to have some of the fields to be given as "None" and be translated to ":" (to give the full table for that variable).

Answer (score 1):

> For example, rather than accessing the values as table[16][5][17][14]
>   I'd prefer to access them somehow using variable names/values

That's what `numpy`'s `dtype`s are for:

```
  dt = [('L','float64'),('T','float64'),('NMSF','float64'),('err','float64')]
  data = plb.loadtxt(argv[1],dtype=dt)
```

Now you can access the `data` elements using `date['T']['L']['NMSF']`

More info on dtypes:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html